# 'Access control allow origin' Not working on different system

Tags: angularjs, django, windows, google-chrome, django-cors-headers

I am using Django for Rest API and Angularjs for front-end.
I have set the header in Django to give API access to a domain (www.example.com).

The code is working fine, I am able to make ajax calls, from my system (OS - MAC, Browser : Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Android chrome, Native browser). Almost everything.

Now suddenly I am getting this error, on specific OS:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.apicalls.in/. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I am getting this problem on Windows 10 Chrome browser (Both OS have same chrome version - 46.x.x.x). I am unable to understand this behavior since the API is working fine with all the other devices with same browser. Anyone faced this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

If your server is configured correctly (I mean, it respects the CORS specification), then it may be a cache problem.

If you have retrieved `http://www.apicalls.in/` in your browser before your ajax, (That is to say, you have triggered a GET request to `http://www.apicalls.in/` with no `Origin` in your request header. )
then your server would serve the web page with no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in response. Your next ajax request to the same URL would hit the browser cache and blocked by the browser because of the same origin restriction.

To fix this, you could add a random param to your request url (e.g. `http://www.apicalls.in/?_=123`) or open up the developer tool of chrome and checked on `disable cache`. Good luck :)